# how can i create an update function with out using form in symfony 5

Tags: sql-update, edit, symfony-forms, symfony5

i want to update for exemple contact entity without using form
and i don't know how
this is my code :

```
/** 
 * @Route("/UpdateContact/{id}",name="editcontact")
 */
public function EditContact(Contact $Contact , Request $request ,ManagerRegistry $manager)
{

    $contact = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Contact::class)
        ->findAll();

    $request->get('responsable');
    $request->get('telephone');
    $request->get('email');
    $request->get('note');
     
    $contact->setResponsable($request->request->get('responsable'))
            ->setTelephone ($request->request->get('telephone'))
            ->setEmail ($request->request->get('email'))
            ->setNote ($request->request->get('note'));
            $manager->persist($contact);
            $manager->flush();
    return $this->render('companyProfile.html.twig', [
        // 'contactform'=>$contactform->createView(),
        'Contact' => $contact,
     ]);
  }
```

it dosen't work so if anyone know how to update without a form , plz help me i'm stuck right now

Answer (score 0):

You need `EntityManagerInterface` instead of `ManagerRegistry`

So your code needs to be like this:

```
<?php

public function EditContact(Contact $contact, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
        $contact
            ->setResponsable($request->get('responsable'))
            ->setTelephone($request->get('telephone'))
            ->setEmail($request->get('email'))
            ->setNote($request->get('note'))
        ;

        $em->persist($contact);
        $em->flush();

        // rest of your code
}
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database